# While using Vim extension in VS Code, is there a way to reset vim mode to normal every time I navigate between files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Lets say Im at file X, later on when Im at file Y and I want to go back to file X, file X will be in the mode that I left it with, in this case Insert Mode. But I want to reset to normal mode every time I re open a file. The reason I want to do this is because while navigating files I dont remember which mode I left it on, so I'd prefer to reset to normal mode